# RingtoneManager android 11

Tags: ringtonemanager

I used below code for set Ringtone
**But has error For android 11**

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, outputfile.getAbsolutePath());
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ringtonename");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, getMIMEType(ringtone_file.getPath()));
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, outputfile.length());
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "ringtonename");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri generalaudiouri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        contentResolver.delete(generalaudiouri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "='" + outputfile.getAbsolutePath() + "'", null);
        Uri ringtoneuri = contentResolver.insert(generalaudiouri, contentValues);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, ringtoneuri);
```

> ```
> 2021-10-11 14:53:03.037 10319-10319/com.bestappsringtones.ringtonesforandroidfree I/Toast:
> ```
>
> show: focusDisplayId = 0, isFocusInDesktop = false mCustomDisplayId=-1
> isDexDualMode=false 2021-10-11 14:53:03.037
> 10319-10319/com.bestappsringtones.ringtonesforandroidfree I/Toast:
> show: isActivityContext = true 2021-10-11 14:53:03.106
> 10319-10319/com.bestappsringtones.ringtonesforandroidfree
> W/RingtoneManager: Failed to open directly; attempting failover:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
> directory) 2021-10-11 14:53:03.114
> 10319-10319/com.bestappsringtones.ringtonesforandroidfree
> W/RingtoneManager: Failed to cache ringtone: java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.SecurityException: Uri is not ringtone, alarm, or
> notification: content://0@media/external/audio/media/56062 2021-10-11
> 14:53:03.114 10319-10319/com.bestappsringtones.ringtonesforandroidfree
> I/RingtoneManager: Save path type :1, URI :
> content://0@media/external/audio/media/56062 2021-10-11 14:53:03.132
> 10319-10319/com.bestappsringtones.ringtonesforandroidfree
> I/RingtoneManager: ringtone path:
> /storage/emulated/0/Music/1633951383000.oga 2021-10-11 14:53:03.148
> 10319-10319/com.bestappsringtones.ringtonesforandroidfree D/Toast:
> show: caller =
> com.bestappsringtones.ringtonesforandroidfree.SettingActivity